# Wrapping in Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

I know the Python coding standard has a limit of 78 characters per line. I am working in Notepad++ and
how do I set it so it wraps after 78 characters?

Comment: it's not about automated wrapping, you should write you code in a way that it should not exceed character limit

Comment: @Domber Check out this question on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/414209/notepad-80-character-line-marker

Answer (score 6):

There's a good writeup in the Notepad++ User Manual about [managing line lengths](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/#editing). It suggests using the  Settings -> Preferences -> Editing -> Vertical edge settings. There doesn't appear to be a way to have it automatically wrap to a new line as you are typing.

Comment: Notepad++ wiki has moved since the original answer to this question. Functionality checked and is working in Notepad++ 6.6.7.

Comment: The Notepad++ wiki seems to have vanished, but now there is a new and better User Manual.

Answer (score 0):

To apply the WordWrap, just goo to view in the Menu bar and check the WordWrap option.

Comment: This only changes the way lines are displayed, that doesn't wrap the line within the file.